# How can I transfer photos from camera to iPhone?

Tags: dslr, sdcard, iphone

I know how to copy photos from SD card to my laptop. But how can I move them to my new iPhone 7 plus?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using Lightning to USB Camera Adapter cable. This cable lets you connect your DSLR with I phone directly. Connect the lightning end to  your Iphone and connect the camera cable to the USB end. Switch on the camera, and open the Photo app in you Iphone. You will see a new menu called Import in your Iphone next to Photos | Albums | etc at the bottom. Tap to select the photos which you need to transfer. All the transfered photos will be in a new album called Imported Photos. Give a try. The cable cost around 20USD. Option 2  is to use wifi if your camera has a built - in adapter. Or else you need to buy a wifi adapter for you camera, which is more costly than the lightning to USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways I use for this transfer.
One is to use the lightning cable and transfer the photos using itunes on your computer.
Second is create a shared photos folder using iclouds. So, whatever photos you add in this folder they get downloaded on your iphone (provided you have to be connected through wifi).

PS: My camera doesn't have wifi and I don't have the lighting to USB Camera Adapter cable.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on which camera you have. For instance, for Nikon, there's an app, Nikon WMU which can be used to take photos remotely and also to transfer photos from camera to phone and vice-versa by connecting the camera and the phone via wifi.
When I'm one the move I just what to quickly share a snap, I tag on camera the photo(s) I want to pass, connect the camera to the phone via wifi, open the program and this will automatically pass the photo(s).

Answer (score -3):

Even simpler : Email them from your computer to your phone.

Comment: This solution doesn't scale well _at all_. It might be fine for a small handful of photos, but email is usually limited on attachment size, and sometimes number of attachments. That means manually "binning" photos a few at a time in email. And _then_, once on the phone, you usually need to go through the process of saving photos to your camera's library. For 10 photos, sure. But hundreds (or more)... ugh.